# How to remove similar items from a list of lists

Tags: python, list, product

EDITED DESCRIPTION:

> Let's say I have a set of linear functions. I am tasked with comparing
> features. Let's say our "length" is going to be the slope of the
> linear function. Let's say "multi" is going to be a factor of b. Now:
>
> 1. I don't want to compare the same linear functions. 2. I don't want to compare linear functions twice. Because if we put the coefficients
>    together in such an iterator, we generate the same line

I have two lists. I need the product of two lists, but two lists I will use twice - something like this: `itertools.product(l1, l2, l1, l2)`.

The problem is that I have similar (not duplicated) items in output.

I wrote this code but it is ultra slow for longer lists:

```
import itertools

lenght = [1, 2]
multi = [3, 4]

iter = itertools.product(lenght, multi, lenght, multi)

l = []
try:
    while True:
        l.append(list(next(iter)))
except:
    pass

for inter_list in l:
    print(inter_list)

print()

"BELOW IS SOLUTION BUT SLOW."

for l_master in l:
    if l_master[0] == l_master[2] and l_master[1] == l_master[3] :
        print("Step1: remove > ", l_master)
        l.remove(l_master)

print()
for l_master in l:
    print(l_master)
    l_slave = l_master[:]
    l_slave.append(l_slave.pop(0))
    l_slave.append(l_slave.pop(0))

    print("Step2 remove >>, ", l_slave)
    l.remove(l_slave)
print( )
for k in l:
    print(k)
```

This gives me:

```
[1, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 1, 3]
[1, 4, 1, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
[2, 4, 1, 3]
[2, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 4, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 2, 4]


Step1: remove >  [1, 3, 1, 3]
Step1: remove >  [1, 4, 1, 4]
Step1: remove >  [2, 3, 2, 3]
Step1: remove >  [2, 4, 2, 4]

[1, 3, 1, 4]
Step2 remove >>,  [1, 4, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
Step2 remove >>,  [2, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
Step2 remove >>,  [2, 4, 1, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
Step2 remove >>,  [2, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
Step2 remove >>,  [2, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
Step2 remove >>,  [2, 4, 2, 3]


[1, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
```

That means that I need only one item from pair: `[1, 3, 1, 4]` and `[1, 4, 1, 3]`. It does not matter which one.

I also do not need rows like:

```
[1, 3, 1, 3]
[1, 4, 1, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 3]
[2, 4, 2, 4]
```

How to build output like I need?
I think I will need something else than `itertools.product` or a completely new solution.

EDITED:
Desired output:

```
[1, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
```

Comment: So, what is the rule?  Absolutely no duplicated values?  In that case, there are only 4 possible sequences: `1,3,2,4`, `1,4,2,3`, `2,3,1,4`, and `2,4,1,3`.  Right?  You would be better off with nested loops instead of using `itertools.product` here.  You could use `permutations` to get all combinations of 2 items from each list, then interleave those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
from itertools import product, combinations

lenght = [1, 2]
multi = [3, 4]

for a, b in combinations(product(lenght, multi), 2):
    print(list(a + b))
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VY47DsIwEER7n2LKWJiCT4GQOAlK4YSErBR7LXtT5CZINGngTtwGQ0LBdKPRPL37M4zSsZ-mxyDt-vC6tZEdSJoozH0CucBRECJfhloManYVeSvEPinVN_7aCU44bwy2pXJDL_SpO4N9qVTLEdagAvm_Z7Hwihlg8D3qzNBHhZwQyeeVkhQWK1Raz36L5k_3DQ)):

```
[1, 3, 1, 4]
[1, 3, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2, 4]
[1, 4, 2, 3]
[1, 4, 2, 4]
[2, 3, 2, 4]
```